# Spring Data Neo4j OGM return apoc.coll.intersection from repository method

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have the following Spring Data Neo4j OGM Repository method:

```
@Query("MATCH (root:Location) " +
        "WHERE root.id IN $locationIds " +
        "WITH root " +
        "OPTIONAL MATCH (root)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(descendant:Location) " +
        "OPTIONAL MATCH (ascendant:Location)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(root) " +
        "WITH COLLECT(root.id) AS listRoot, COLLECT( DISTINCT ascendant.id) AS listAscendant, COLLECT( DISTINCT descendant.id) AS listDescendant WITH apoc.coll.union(listDescendant, apoc.coll.union(listRoot, listAscendant)) AS dadLocationIds " +
        "WITH dadLocationIds " +
        "RETURN apoc.coll.intersection(dadLocationIds, $specifiedLocationIds) as output")
Set<Long> locationsHaveAnyDirectOrAscendantOrDescendantRelationshipsWithSpecifiedLocations(Set<Long> locationIds, Set<Long> specifiedLocationIds);
```

this method fails with the following exception:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type [@org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Query java.util.Set<java.lang.Long>] for value '[[5]]'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.Collections$SingletonList<?>] to type [@org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Query java.lang.Long]
```

How to properly return `Set` of ids for intersection?

**UPDATED**

```
MATCH (root:Location) 
            WHERE root.id IN [61]
            WITH root 
            OPTIONAL MATCH (root)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(descendant:Location) 
            OPTIONAL MATCH (ascendant:Location)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(root) 
            WITH COLLECT(root.id) AS listRoot, COLLECT(DISTINCT ascendant.id) AS listAscendant, COLLECT(DISTINCT descendant.id) AS listDescendant 
            WITH listDescendant + listRoot + listAscendant AS dadLocationIds
            WITH dadLocationIds 
            WITH apoc.coll.intersection(dadLocationIds, [60, 58]) as output
            RETURN output
```

and output from Neo4j browser:

```
╒════════╕
│"output"│
╞════════╡
│[60]    │
└────────┘
```

**UPDATED 1**

The query works fine when I change it to the following:

```
 "WITH apoc.coll.intersection(dadLocationIds, $specifiedLocationIds) as intersectionIds " +
        "MATCH (l:Location) WHERE l.id IN intersectionIds " +
        "RETURN l")
Set<Location> locationsHaveAnyDirectOrAscendantOrDescendantRelationshipsWithSpecifiedLocations(Set<Long> locationIds, Set<Long> specifiedLocationIds);
```

Comment: is this the value of  $specifiedLocationIds = '[[5]]'?  Can you use List instead of Set?

Comment: this is just a plain Java Set. Also changed to the List.. unfortunately with the same result (

Comment: '[[5]]' is the result from intersection. Also, when I change the query to the `RETURN (10) as output` it works fine. Hot to convert [5] to (5) ?

Comment: Is the error coming for the same set of parameters as the ones provided in the sample neo4j browser query?

Comment: yes, the same set

Comment: Okk, interesting there is no value 5 in the parameters and in the result

Comment: oh.. no.. each time I run the test, I have the different IDs generated

Comment: Please see my updated question. If I change the return type to the Set<Location> - everything works fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is returning `List<List<Long>>` I think, most probably because of the line:

```
WITH COLLECT(root.id) AS listRoot, COLLECT( DISTINCT ascendant.id) AS listAscendant, COLLECT( DISTINCT descendant.id) AS listDescendant WITH apoc.coll.union(listDescendant, apoc.coll.union(listRoot, listAscendant)) AS dadLocationIds
```

This line might be causing multiple lists to get created, for each one the intersection gets performed, and hence the final output becomes `List<List<Long>>`. Try running this on Neo4j Browser, to see if this is true or not:

```
 MATCH (root:Location) 
 WHERE root.id IN $locationIds
 WITH root 
 OPTIONAL MATCH (root)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(descendant:Location)
 OPTIONAL MATCH (ascendant:Location)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(root)
 WITH COLLECT(root.id) AS listRoot, COLLECT( DISTINCT ascendant.id) AS listAscendant, COLLECT( DISTINCT descendant.id) AS listDescendant
 RETURN apoc.coll.union(listDescendant, apoc.coll.union(listRoot, listAscendant)) AS dadLocationIds
```

If there are multiple lists in the output, for the parameters that you tried with. Then the query needs to be fixed.

**Update:**

I got it. When you specify return type as `Set<Long>`, `Spring` is expecting `neo4j` to return `Long` values, which it will place in a `set`. However, when you return `apoc.coll.intersection` output, it tries to put that `List<Long>` into a `Set<Long>`, due to which the error comes up. To fix this, you can simply `UNWIND` the list from `apoc.coll.intersection` and return it. Like this:

```
MATCH (root:Location) 
WHERE root.id IN [61]
WITH root 
OPTIONAL MATCH (root)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(descendant:Location) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ascendant:Location)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(root) 
WITH COLLECT(root.id) AS listRoot, COLLECT(DISTINCT ascendant.id) AS listAscendant, COLLECT(DISTINCT descendant.id) AS listDescendant 
WITH listDescendant + listRoot + listAscendant AS dadLocationIds
WITH dadLocationIds 
WITH apoc.coll.intersection(dadLocationIds, [60, 58]) as output
UNWIND output AS locationId
RETURN locationId
```

Comment: It returns the following: [48,49,47]

Comment: Ohk, then the query is good. What is the output of the whole query on Neo4j Browser (With intersection) and make sure that the params are same in both places.

Comment: Please see the updated question with this info